# SD card lifetime optimization

Tags: sd-card, flash-memory

Simple question:

Which approach is best in terms of prolonging the life expectancy of an SD card?
Writing 10-minute files with 10 Hz lines of data input (~700 kB each) 
1) directly to the SD card
or
2) to the internal memory of the device, then moving the file to the SD card
?

The amount of data being written to the SD card remains the same. The question is simply if a lot of tiny file operations (6000 lines written in the course of ten minutes, 100 ms apart) or one file operation moving the entire file containing the 6000 lines onto the card as once is better. Or does it even matter? Of course the card specifications are hugely important as well, but let's leave that out of the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should only write to fill flash page boundaries discussed here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227686/sd-card-sector-size

2) Keeping fault-tolerant track of how much data is written where also needs to be written.  That counts as a write hit on FAT etc as well, on a page that gets more traffic than others.  Avoid if possible (ie fdup/fclose/fopen append) techniques which cause buffer and directory cached data to be flushed.  But I would use this trick every minute or so so you never lose more than a minute of data on a crash or accidental removal.

3) OS-supported wear leveling will solve the above, if properly implemented. I have read horror stories about flash memories being destroyed in days.

4) Calculate expected life using the total wear-leveled lifetime writes spec of that memory.  Usually in TB's.  If you see numbers in the decades, don't bother doing more than (1).

5) Which OS and file-system you are using matters somewhat.  For example EXT3 is supposedly faster than EXT2 due to less drive access at a slightly higher risk ratio.  Since your question doesn't ask about OS/FS you use, I'll leave the rest of that up to you.